# Django migrations for foreign key does not reflect in MySQL database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations, django-mysql

This is my migration file named `0004_auto_20190218_1614.py`. I ran `makemigrations` and `migration` command. All the other addition and deletion of columns are successful but in this case where I have added a foreign key the changes have not been reflected in database. When I try to insert the record.

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.5 on 2019-02-18 10:44`

    from django.db import migrations, models
    import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('projectName', '0003_auto_20190218_1604'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='projectdetails',
            name='userdetails',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='projectName.UserDetails'),
        ),
    ]
```

I get this exception

`_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown column 'userdetails_id' in 'field list'`

and then this:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I am newbie in Django. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you calling strip()

Comment: I am not calling strip() in views.py. In fact I tried finding using Ctrl+F 'strip' does not exist in my file

Comment: you need to run userdetails table migration first and then this one

Comment: You mean migration for each table individually?

Comment: use python manage.py showmigrations to see which all migrations are applied

Comment: Have you created table with `syncdb` first, and then trying to change the table structure in later migration? Because, I had same error once due to that.

Comment: @JibinMathews I got the name of the 0004_auto_20190218_1614.py under my project name. I guess it has been applied

Comment: @BidhanMajhi shows deprecated

Answer (score 0):

from your `DB-Models`, you can able to see a table named `django-migrations`. Here you will find all applied migrations. One of the possible reason is that you have manually deleted some of your migrations file but there reference unfortunately keep in `django-migrations` table. One of the possible solution is to delete those applied-migrations and run safely `python manage.py migrate` command again.

#### N.B: Don't delete any of migrations that have physical effect in models already. what i want to say, model data are available for those migrations effect. Better dumb your dB and then do this if you are not fully sure about that.

Comment: I did get a duplicate file in my migrations which was not there physically in my current file list. I have deleted and made migrations again. But still did not get my foreign key

Comment: whenever you delete any migrations and add new one, please make sure the serial and dependencies  are properly in sync If everything is fine django should not merge any two commits. If django ask for that merge then definitely serial is not same. Also you need to check applied migrations serial from `django-migrations` table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `migrate` command and check your database for updates.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the applied changes in model may not be reflected in the database. The easiest way is to delete your migrations files inside migrations folder(except **init**.py) and again run `python manage.py makemigrations`.
Or you may use `south migrations` for effectively reflecting your migrations in database.

Docs for `south migrations` can be found in:
https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/